# Python function recalls itself after return statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

The question is rather academic. I came across the following behaviour in python:

This Code:

```
def dosth():
   print("new")
   for n in range(0,10):
       return False
dosth()
```

actually gives me 10 prints instead of one. So does the function recursively call itself after the return statement because there is no break?
If I put in a break before the return statement I still get 2 prints instead of only one. 
Can someone explain this behaviour

Comment: I know - It is not code I want to use, this is just curiosity. Yes n is being looped for 10 calls but it should return after the first so how can there then be another print? Besides the print is not even in the loop.

Comment: So when I try this program, I only see it print once. Are you sure your formatting is consistent? Check output here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lqjB7iJHCzpiSYWsQl0_oMiYQFRM8MuX

Answer (score 0):

I only see one `new` printed.

It also appears that you're a missing a colon `:` at the end of your loop `for n in range(0,10)`.

```
def dosth():
   print("new")
   for n in range(0,10):
       return False
dosth()
# prints 'new' once...
```